# How to maintain two Openssl version(1.1 and 3.0) in single Mac and connect with two svn version website.?

Tags: macos, openssl, subversion

I have local subversion website which supports only openssl@1.1 but My Mac is upgrade to latest it works Openssl@3. I am able install oldest openssl@1.1 but I am able set path with this. while connecting it was use openssl@3 only.

What is proper way install openssl@1.1 in MacOS 14.?